# Removing data in a string using wildcard

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm trying to remove all data from the string after and including the "/"

```
$price="10/3"
```

I have tried preg_replace

```
$str = '2016/19';
$change = str_replace('/','-',$str);
$pattern = '/-*/';  
$new = preg_replace($pattern,'',$change);
```

I tried doing it the way above because didn't know if there was issues with slashes so I changed the string to 2016-19 and then tried to replace the pattern But it doesn't remove the data following the -it simply removes the -

Also I can't do a substr because the amount of digits before the / and after change

Comment: You need to escape `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly right.

```
$str = '2016/19';
// escape "/" by using "\/"
// .*$ matches any character up to the end of the string denoted by "$"
$pattern = '/\/.*$/';
$new = preg_replace($pattern,'',$str);

echo $new;
```

Comment: Regular expressions need to be enclosed by a starting and matching ending character. Most people use "/" like in the example above. Indeed many characters can be used which makes this a valid regex, too: "#/.*$#". No need to escape "/" here.

Comment: BRILLIANT ! knew it was something simple I was missing !

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = '2016/19';
$result = (explode("/", $str)[0]); //get the part before "/" after splitting
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php